Native compiling and running user code
I would like to write some Emacs Lisp code in a .el file, compile it natively to a .eln file, and run it like a script.  I managed to compile to .eln but I don't know how to run it (running emacs --script gives Error: void-variable (ELF) error).  I tried to make it a "package" by adding provide to it and updating load-path, but Emacs didn't automatically compile it to .eln like it does other packages.  Does anyone know how to achieve this?  I am running Emacs 29.4.

I don't believe you can evaluate native-compiled code with --script.
You can just load it, though.  E.g.:
emacs -batch -l /tmp/eg-ed52f154-04bdccfc.eln


That was it.  Thank you so much!  I also found on atcoder how they compile and run Emacs Lisp submissions: emacs --batch -f package-initialize --eval '(native-compile "Main.el" (expand-file-name "Main.eln"))'
